# PHP - How to get images from Instagram without API Access Token

Tags: php, instagram

Can I get images from Instagram Profile without Instagram API or Access token?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get all images. Just iterate them by `page_info`. In addition, there is more convenient way to get json:

```
$otherPage = 'nasa';
$profileUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/$otherPage/?__a=1";

$iterationUrl = $profileUrl;
$tryNext = true;
$limit = 100;
$found = 0;
while ($tryNext) {
    $tryNext = false;
    $response = file_get_contents($iterationUrl);
    if ($response === false) {
        break;
    }
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($data === null) {
        break;
    }
    $media = $data['user']['media'];
    $found += count($media['nodes']);
    var_dump($media['nodes']);
    if ($media['page_info']['has_next_page'] && $found < $limit) {
        $iterationUrl = $profileUrl . '&max_id=' . $media['page_info']['end_cursor'];
        $tryNext = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instagram, they changed the structure of public json
from $data['user']['media'] to $data['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'] :(

Comment: Next page value not getting its return same page images